# How can I get the img flush in the corner?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently my `img` for this card looks like this: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ss1syudL/3/)

This is part of the reactjs component:

```
<div className='col-lg-4 emp-row'>
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                            <img src={this.props.details.avatar} alt=""/>
                        </div>
                <div className="col-lg-8">
                            <div>
                            <span className='name'> {this.props.details.firstName} &nbsp;
                                {this.props.details.lastName}</span>
                            <div>
                                    {this.props.details.bio.slice(0, 80)}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Notice how there are spaces around the `img`? I tried to change the height but it does not help.

How can I get the img to display like this:?

Comment: Do you mean fully flush into the upper-left corner, or the entire left-hand side? I made a minor [fiddle change here](https://jsfiddle.net/ss1syudL/4/), but I'm not sure if it's close to what you want, but the image is in the same position though.

Comment: @PaulT. I updated the design to clarify

Comment: You're not using the Bootstrap grid correctly - `col-` elements must be children of a `row` to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the padding around the `img` containers:

```
.emp-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* padding: 10px 0;     <--- remove */
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-lg-4 {    
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
   /* padding-left: 15px;    <--- remove  */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ss1syudL/5/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap, so the **col-lg-4** has padding defined, thus you have 2 choices.

Add an extra class to the div containing the image and define
    padding as zero.

Add a class to the images and define css like:

```
<img class='mugshot' src='.../etc'>

.mugshot{
margin: -10px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```